# function return not assigned to a variable

Tags: function, return-value

What if you call a (non-void) function, but don't assign its return value to a variable? 
e.g., getchar();

I've always wondered what happens to such a value. I've heard humorous explanations like "its gone to the ether" and so forth, but I'd really like to know really. Would there be any way to recover such a value?
Thanks

Comment: No idea why java allows function to be called without assignment to a variable when the function has some return type

Answer (score 4):

No, you won't.

The value gets popped off the stack and is gone.

If you need the return value, you should assign it to a variable.

Comment: Most calling conventions use a register for return values. So nothing pops of the stack.

Answer (score 4):

This is really compiler / CPU specific, but in most cases the return value will be in a CPU register (if it will fit), and if that register is not touched by the subsequent code, you could retrieve it using e.g. "inline assembler".

To answer your question better, nothing "happens" to the value. It sits in a stack-location or inside a register. If you use it, fine... if not, nothing happens really. Eventually the stack or register is overwritten by new values...

Answer (score 0):

Simply 'returning' (either by implicitly calling return by itself or not returning at all) and not assigning a value does just that, doesn't assign a value and thus is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn more about how it all works, you can look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack