# Implications of not assigning the return value of a function to a variable

Tags: c++, stack, undefined-behavior

I'm going through some introductory C++ exercises, one of which is: What's going to be on the screen after running this code:

```
int& testMethod (int& a){

    int c = a+a;
    return c;
};

int main() {
    int z = 5;
    int* y = new int (testMethod(z));
    int r = 25;
    testMethod(r);
    std::cout<<*y;
    return 0;
}
```

My questions are:

1. Am I right that this is an example of UB as the value returned by `testMethod` on the second call is not getting assigned to a variable?
2. Is it true that the return value, although not assigned to a variable, might still be recovered but it depends?

For No 2, I'm just trying to confirm my understanding of how the stack works, which is as follows. When a function returns a value and the value gets assigned to a variable, the result of the calculations is firstly stored on the stack as `retval` at some memory location and then gets assigned to the variable, i.e. written to another memory location. The stack pointer then moves up (again, from what I understand, the 'top' of the stack is actually its 'bottom' as the pointer moves from the largest address to the smallest). But `retval` is still there for some time until it gets overwritten by another piece of data (which might happen almost instantly).

This second question arose when I was looking for an answer to the first question on SO and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198356/function-return-not-assigned-to-a-variable) thread, as the two top (by votes) posts answer differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How automatic allocation is implemented on your particular platform is irrelevant. Your codes *does* trigger UB, not because you ignore the return value of `testMethod` (which, by the way, is *not* a method) but on the contrary because the following line uses it:

```
int* y = new int (testMethod(z));
```

The issue is that `testMethod` always returns a dangling reference to what was its local variable `c`. Using this reference to initialize the dynamically-allocated `int` triggers UB.

Predictably, enabling warnings (which you should always do) produces the following:

```
warning: reference to stack memory associated with local variable 'c' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]
```

Comment: Wait, that's an eye-opener. That's how I have always returned a value from a function: created a local variable within the function, stored the result of whatever calculations into that variable and returned the variable. You're saying this is always UB? What's the correct way then? Or is it because `testMethod` returns a reference instead of the integer itself?

Comment: As a side note, the compiler didn't produce any warnings upon running the code (I'm using Visual Studio 2017), although I'm pretty sure they are enabled as I'm seeing some all the time.

Comment: @JohnAllison if you return a value then there is no problem. The issue is that you return a reference. It is similar to do something like that `int* foo() { int* x = new int; delete x; return x; }`. You would never write code like that, but thats kind of analog to what you do when you return a reference to a local variable (that gets deleted when it leaves scope)

Comment: @user463035818, got it, thanks for the crystal clear example.

Comment: @JohnAllison note that the example in my comment alone has no undefined behaviour, only when you dereference the pointer ...bang... Similar with returning a refernce. The difference is that you cannot do anything meaningful with a dangling reference (while you could reassign a new adress to an invalid pointer)

Comment: @Quentin, turning back to the stack question, does the first sentence in the answer imply that the stack may be implemented differently on different platforms, architectures or whatnot?

Comment: @JohnAllison exactly. C++ itself avoids using the word "stack", preferring the term "automatic lifetime".

Answer (score 3):

> Am I right that this is an example of UB as the value returned by
>   testMethod on the second call is not getting assigned to a variable?

Maybe you didnt notice yet, but you are ignoring the returned value all the time (sloppy speaking). For example `std::cout << *y;` returns a reference to `std::cout`, otherwise you could not chain it as in

```
std::cout << "hello" << "world";
```

No. Ignoring the returned value is not undefined. Sometimes you cannot avoid to ignore the returned value (just another example: assignment usually returns a reference, ie you can write `a = b = c;` but usually you just write `b = c; a = b;`).

For 2) you are too much considering implementation details. Dont overcomplicate it. You ignore the value, thats all.

PS: your code has UB, but for completely different reason (see [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53445178/4117728)).